# How to include other NPM modules when publishing to NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to publish my first module to NPM, it renders markdown with EJS templating, it uses two other npm modules marked and ejs, I have these as dependencies in my `package.json` file. I have a `.gitignore` file that contains my `node_modules` directory, and also a `.npmignore` file that is empty.

I have successfully published to npm.

However when I try to install my module by putting it into the `package.json` of a test app and doing `npm install -d` it installs, but it does not install its dependencies, if I go into the test app root `node_modules` directory and then into my newly published module's installed directory, It has not installed any of its dependencies, it has not have a nested `node_modules` directory of its own.

There should be a way to get my module's dependencies to install with it correct, when I include express as a dependency, it installs its own node_modules folder with connect and other modules installed, I want to do the same with two other npm modules.

I know it would work if it would install its nested `node_modules` dependencies, when I do this it works.

```
$ npm install -d
$ cd node_modules/my_module
$ npm install -d
$ cd ../..
$ node app
```

**EDIT:** Here is a link to the [**GitHub repo**](https://github.com/CoryG89/markedejs) for my module, and here is the [**package.json**](https://github.com/CoryG89/markedejs/blob/master/package.json).

**EDIT:** Note, this has only happens when I had my dependencies **marked** and **ejs** already installed in my test app. When I then installed my module, it did not install marked and ejs in its own `node_modules` directory. However, if I remove all modules from the test app and install only my module, it will install them. Is there anyway to get it to work regardless of whether my dependencies have been installed beforehand.

Comment: Could you post the `package.json` contents?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Added links

Comment: I just installed your package and got all the deps installed... npm 1.2.18 and node v0.10.6

Comment: Apparently the problem is that my test app already had ejs and marked installed, I figured it would just be installed at both levels, apparently it will just not install the dependencies at all if they are already present. Is there anyway to use my module which depends on ejs in an app that already has ejs installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should all "just work" as is.

npm does not install any new modules, because it sees there are already appropriate modules in a node_modules directory at a higher level. Because node's `require` will look up into the tree, trying node_modules subdir for each directory, your module's `require` statements will work, without having a node_modules directory of its own.

If you'd install the module in any place which does not have the right dependencies already installed, they would be installed under the module's own node_modules directory. Alberto confirmes this.

You may want to specify a more specific version of the dependencies in package.json though. This will ensure your module gets to use the version of the dependencies you have tested it with.

Comment: After reading this, I messed with it some more, uninstalled all the dependencies again, installed them and it is working as you say. Not sure what was wrong before though. It was not able to require the modules.